# Spotify Tutorial example app is blank

Tags: spotify

I'm having trouble getting the tutorial project working. I've placed it under homedir/Spotify/Tutorial

In side spotify i enter spotify:app:Tutorial and it asks me if i want to add it to the side bar, which i do. When choosing it its a blank page. Opening up the inspector i see this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Any clues whats wrong? I'm running spotify version 0.8.0.952.g.0298b8ce and i have a developer account.

Thanks in advance
/Eric

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I take a working app and rename it with a capital letter I get the same behaviour you are describing, try renaming your directory from Tutorial to tutorial then load the app with spotify:app:tutorial

Comment: Yep, can confirm that Spotify only appears to like app folder names in lowercase. Had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I was scratching my head for quite a while, there. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you look at index.html in the body tag there is a variable call 'tutorial' I believe it calls for that when you ask for spotify:app:tutorial since there is no 'Tutorial' variable it returns nothing.