# Spotify apps / home directory location (Windows local development)?

Tags: spotify

My development account for Spotify has been enabled and I am trying to walk through their simple tutorial app (http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/tutorial/).  I should note here that I am on a Win 7 workstation.

When I try to load the local app by typing 'spotify:app:Tutorial' in the search field I get the following msg/error:  **"Sorry, I could find this app.  metadatafailed URI: spotify:app:Tutorial Error: appNotFound."**

I have tried adding the app files to the following directories and still getting the error:

- C:\Users\Me\Documents\Spotify\Tutorial (note this dir did not exist I created it)
- C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Spotify
- C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Spotify\Users\me-user
- C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Spotify
- C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Users\me-user

So where exactly are you suppose to add the files so that Spotify will load local apps?

Thanks!

Comment: I restarted Spotify and then it worked.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://github.com/mager/spotify-apps-tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first guess is correct (C:\Users\Me\Documents\Spotify\Tutorial). However you need to be running the latest preview release (https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/). And on my PC I had to completely un-install and reinstall the application before the developer options became enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I uninstalled Spotify & installed  the preview version from the link you provided.  I also placed a copy of the Tutorial app files in my documents home dir (C:\Users\Me\Documents\Spotify\Tutorial).  However, I am still receiving the same error message I originally noted.  Here is a screenshot that may be helpful (http://goo.gl/9YRkP).  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you unblock the zip file before extracting it? You might want to try hooking [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) up to Spotify before attempting to load the Tutorial app. It should show you where spotify is looking.

Comment: I followed the same steps you originally outlined on my home workstation and it worked! If I still have problems on my other WS I will try your suggestions w/ Process Monitor (makes sense).  As for the link that Niklas Berglund provided that came into play as well, but for the purposes of my original question the information you provided answered it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it helps in your case, but try naming the folder tutorial with lowercase t. See [Spotify Tutorial example app is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719182/spotify-tutorial-example-app-is-blank)

Comment: @ Niklas Berglund  Thanks for the link.  After I was finally able to get the app loaded the link you provided came into play.  Thanks for providing this information!  I would love to give credit to you both, but the information 'akakjs' provided was more relevant to my initial issue...so will document that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment, but I was having the same issues and had to do a combination of what Niklas and akakjs did.  I had to completely uninstall the spotify app, download/install the preview version, create a Spotify directory in My Documents, then create the folder Tutorial.  Then, in the Spotify search bar I had to type "spotify:app:tutorial" with the lowercase t.  I hope this helps!

Comment: In the end I had to do a combination of both steps as well.  The information 'akakjs' provided allowed me to load the app without error  & the information 'Niklas Berglund' provided fixed issue with no data showing up.  Thanks for your comment...hopefully this thread will help out more folks down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem. I had to `run Spotify as administrator`, worked right away.

And the path i used were: `C:\Users\me\Documents\Spotify`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Spotify could not find my app directory even though the proper folder had been created in my Documents folder.

I Fixed it by running Spotify as an Administrator.