# Spotify app "My Documents" folder

Tags: windows-7-x64, spotify

I've seen similar question posted on two other places.

[Spotify apps / home directory location (Windows local development)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756961/spotify-apps-home-directory-location-windows-local-development)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694544/spotify-windows-app-directory

One is closed and one is solved. I get "sorry, i could not find this app." when i search for spotify:app:tutorial. I think it's got to do with that i have moved my "My Documents" folder to another drive. I have uninstalled my old Spotify and installed the latest build. Rebooted my computer many times. Tried to place the tutorial folder (downloaded from spotify) in these locations:

```
D:\JohanB\Documents\Spotify
D:\Users\JohanB\AppData\Local\Spotify
D:\JohanB\Documents\Spotify
D:\JohanB\My Documents\Spotify
C:\Users\JohanB\AppData\Local\Spotify
```

I'm running windows 7 (64bit). How can i figure out where Spotify is searching for local apps?

Comment: Are you registered as a developer? Otherwise, go register here: http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/developer-signup/

Comment: That was it. I just got the confirmation mail from Spotify and now it works. Write it as an answer and i'll mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you registered as a developer? Otherwise, go register here: developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/developer-signup

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you download the latest preview build of our desktop client:

http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/preview/

Also, here is a great tutorial/demo app:

https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the folder in:

```
\Users\JohanB\Documents\Spotify\
```

in either your C or D drive
That is where i put my app folder (with my name instead of JohanB of course :)