# Spotify Tutorial App not found

Tags: spotify

I know very similar questions have been asked before. Like here: [Spotify apps / home directory location (Windows local development)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756961/spotify-apps-home-directory-location-windows-local-development)

But the solutions suggested in that thread have not worked for me. Here's what I've done:

1) Enabled developer account
2) Followed these steps https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/
3) Including creating a directory called "tutorial" under /user/Documents/Spotify/

I have deinstalled, reinstalled, etc the client. And I still get "Sorry, I could not find this app." and "MetaDataFailed" etc.

I run Win 7 64 bit and Spotify version 0.8.3.222.g317ab.79d

I'm sure the solution to this is real simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spotify apps dead after update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error as well, but after adding the required keys (More here: [Application Manifest](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/#applicationmanifest)) I got it working.

Another thing I noticed was that when adding the `BundleIdentifier` key in `manifest.json` I only could get it to work with a lowercase name. E.g. spotify:app:myapp instead of spotify:app:MyApp.

This could of course be something specific on my end, but it is worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me as well. Funny how Spotify don't bother to make their own sample app work.

Comment: I'm developing an app, bouncing between windows and ubuntu. In Windows, I was unsuccessful loading the app until I made my $BUNDLE-IDENTIFIER and folder containing the project all lowercase as @tforssander mentioned above. In ubuntu oddly the directory casing didn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your app name MUST match the identifier you specify for BundleIdentifier in your manifest.json file.

open app: `spotify:app:my-identifier`

manifest.json: `"BundleIdentifier": "my-identifier"`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421944 for moar

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification you are using c:\users[user name]\Documents\Spotify[app name]\ as the folder?  Your post looked like /user was the root.

Also, in your manifest.json file if your BundleVersion is a number equal to or less than the number in production your local app will be ignored.  Spotify will only load a local app with a BundleVersion number higher than production.