# Spotify App directory on Windows XP?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to debug a spotify app in spotify on a windows system. But I'm not able to start the app. I've the same problem which is described in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756961/spotify-apps-home-directory-location-windows-local-development) but on Windows XP the paths are different.

I tried C:\Documents and Settings[user name]\My Documents\Spotify but that doesn't work. Any idea how I can get that to work?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to restart the VM. Than it worked.